# rename video files taking name from subtitles

Tags: bash, scripting

I have several files named as:

`whatever.S02E01.avi` and `What_I_want - 2x01 - blablabla.srt`,

`whatever.S02E02.avi` and `What_I_want - 2x02 - blablablabla.srt`,

and so on.

How can I do to rename the avi files with names taken from the srt files? I need a script that read the name from the srt file compare it with the avi file and if there is a coincidence, e.g., `2x01` matchs with `S02E01`, take the name of the srt file and rename the avi file with the same name.

I have a script that merges srt files with avi files, only if the have the same name.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's always like `xxx[SPACE]-[SPACE]AxB[SPACE]-[SPACE]xxx.srt` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this one:

```
#!/bin/bash

find . -iname "*.avi" | while read f
do

    id=$(echo $f | sed -n 's/.*.S\([0-9]\+\)E\([0-9]\+\)..*/\1x\2/p' | sed 's/^0*//')

    if [ -z "$id" ]; then
        echo "Warning! there's no match for $f"
    else
        srt=(*$id*)
        newName=$(echo $srt | sed 's/.srt/.avi/g')
        mv "$f" "$newName"
    fi

done
```

1. We iterate through all `*.avi` files.
2. Regexp to transform `SE_E_` into `_x_`
3. Second `sed` to remove leading zeroes (`SE02` -> `2x`, not `02x`)
4. Check for existence of the avi file.
5. Renaming of the file.

Comment: Could you explain a little bit?

Comment: What part you don't understand? I thought it was explained